# Server keeps crashing

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx, troubleshooting, server-crashes

I just recently rented a new server which is being used for hosting files and converting them. however for some reason the server keeps crashing every few hours, how can I find out the reason why my server is crashing? is there a log apart from apache's ?

I am currently running apache and nginx on the server (centos), php and perl are installed but there is no mysql.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit here; there isn't enough information to move towards an answer, and we'll just end up spending hours teasing the information out in endless comments.  It will likely be more productive if you try Serverfault chat.

Comment: I know its not much info but what would you generally check to see what caused the crash?? does centos have a log to check?

Comment: It has lots of logs to check.  It's not just going to say "Your server crashed and here is how to fix it", though.

Comment: i understand that but what are the logs to check is the question

Comment: And the answer is "all of them".

Comment: If you're converting files (for whatever that means), are you sure you're not simply running out of RAM during the conversion process?  Look at /var/log/messages for the main system log file.

Comment: You need to provide **lots** more detail Ahoura. What do you mean "crashed"? Does Apache exit or serve HTTP 500 errors? Does the server lock up? Does the server kernel panic? *What specifically happens?*

Comment: It is not apache that is exiting, its the entire server that goes offline. Like it shuts down!

Answer (score 2):

Check the logs. The answer is there:

- [Apache Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html)
- [Some nginx logs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule)

Linux Logs:

- /var/log/message
- /var/log/auth.log
- /var/log/kern.log
- /var/log/secure

Answer (score 1):

The crashing is probably caused (rough guess given your limited information) by an incompatibility issue between nginx and apache. Try running just nginx with phpcgi and see if the problem persists. This would avoid high memory footprint.